# pop-up form doesn't work with jquery content loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using jquery to load my contents. But when the content is loaded, my pop-up form is broken (displayed within the page).

I checked for similar issues but i can't seem to find a working fix.

Should I switch to iframe loading? or is there a way to fix my modal pop-up?

script for content loading:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
           var trigger = $('nav ul li a'),
           container = $('#content'); 

           trigger.on('click', function() {
               var $this = $(this)
               target = $this.data('target');

           container.load(target + '.php');
           return false;
           });
           });
    </script>
```

script for modal pop-up:

```
      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#inquireForm" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          width: 500,
          modal: true,
          resizable: false,
          autoResize: true,
          show: {
            effect: "clip",
            duration: 800
          },
          hide: {
            effect: "drop",
            duration: 800
          }
        });

        $( "#submitForm" ).on( "click", function() {
          $( "#inquireForm" ).dialog( "open" );
          return false;
        });
      } );
      </script>
```

```
         <div id="inquireForm" title="Contact Us">
        <form action="test.php">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address..">
            <label for="number">Contact Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="number" name="contactnumber" placeholder="Your contact number..">
            <label for="project">Project</label>
            <select id="project" name="project">
            <option value="select" label="<--Select a project-->"></option>
            <option value="dasma">Dasma</option>
            <option value="clover">Clover</option>
            <option value="other">Others</option>
          </select>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="How may we help you?" style="height:200px"></textarea>
            <img id="captcha" src="securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" style="float: right; padding-left: 10px; height: 50px;" />
            <input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" style="float: right; width: 110px;" placeholder="Enter Captcha" />
            <!--    <a href="#" style="float: right; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center;" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false"> <br />[ Different Image ]</a>-->

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
      </div>
        <button id="submitForm">Inquire Now!</button>
      </div>
```

Comment: Since there are 2 `</div>` tags It looks like your modal might be inside of the the submit form. It shouldn't be. Place it directly under `<body>` ( I would place it near the close of the body.

Comment: i tried moving my modal, but it's still displaying.

Comment: Like it is displayed all of the time? If so, you could give it a class that would enable `display: none;` and then toggle the class with your button.

Comment: yes, it's displayed all the time. prior to me changing to jquery loading, the modal was working. I tried chaning to div class and added display:none; it's still being displayed.

Comment: Maybe you should give a more complete example. What you are describing sounds like it should be working.